# Will installing a tar.bz2 archive from the Anaconda package repository include dependencies?

Tags: python, r, anaconda, conda

Will installing the tar.bz2 archive from the [Anaconda Package repo](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/repo) include dependencies?

```
conda install <package_name>.tar.bz2
```

Comment: it will not include any dependencies

Answer (score 0):

No it will not. One potential option is to download all the tarballs you need, place them in the `Anaconda3/pkgs` (or `miniconda3/pkgs`), and then run the install in [offline mode](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/overview/#online-and-offline-modes)

```
conda install --offline <package_name>
```